# Should shortbread cookies be lightly browned?

Tags: baking, cookies

I'm trying to make shortbread cookies the proper way. Should they be cooked through, but without any browning? Or, should they be lightly browned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way is acceptable these days, but the classic version declines any browning.

It's really a matter of personal taste. The classic Scottish recipe calls for shortbread to be set but pale. However, many people prefer a bit of light browning, as this tends to emphasize the taste of the salt, which in turn enhances the taste of the butter.